# Editar elementos en una lista en Python

Tags: python

Aun no tengo nuingun codigo escrito, solo busco ayuda en un problema. Digamos que tengo una lista de oraciones:

```
txt = ["Incluye toda la informacion", "quien necesitaría", "hola, como estas", "me alegra saberlo"]
```

Quiero crear otra lista pero que tenga un codigo y en el medio tenga dichas oraciones, ejemplo:

```
txt_1 = ["<code id="2">oracion1</code>", "<code id="7">oracion2</code>", "<code id="221">oracion3</code>", "<code id="216">oracion4</code>"]
```

Que el resultado final sea:

```
txt_2 = ["<code id="2">Incluye toda la informacion</code>", "<code id="7">quien necesitaría</code>", "<code id="221">hola, como estas</code>", "<code id="216">me alegra saberlo</code>"]
```

Nota: el orden siempre sera el mismo, y no puede ser manual porque son muchas las palabras dentro de las listas, sera variable.

Comment: Si entendí bien tu duda, lo que buscas es el uso de un diccionario te recomiendo investigar sobre el uso de diccionarios, aquí tienes un  sitio que te puede ayudar [Diccionarios en Python](https://devcode.la/tutoriales/diccionarios-en-python/)
Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacerlo con `enumerate`, que directamente te devuelve un contador de los elementos:

```
txt = ["Incluye toda la informacion", 
       "quien necesitaría",
       "quien necesitaría", 
       "hola, como estas", 
       "me alegra saberlo"]

print([f'<code id="{i}">{val}</code>' for i, val in enumerate(txt, start=1)])
```

Te devolvería lo siguiente:

```
['<code id="1">Incluye toda la informacion</code>', 
 '<code id="2">quien necesitaría</code>', 
 '<code id="3">quien necesitaría</code>', 
 '<code id="4">hola, como estas</code>', 
 '<code id="5">me alegra saberlo</code>']
```

Si te da igual que empiece en 0 puedes quitar el `start=1`.

Si quisieras un `id` específico para cada elemento tendría que ser de otra manera, pero no has puesto en la pregunta de dónde obtienes dicho `id`.

Answer (score 1):

Primero el código que muestras no es valido pues al poner `"<code id="2">oracion1</code>"` al poner el id cierras las comillas `" "` lo cual en python es una sintaxis invalida, eso se arregla especificando unas comillas diferentes (comillas simples) `' '` en la frase y comillas dobles (`" "`) en el `id`. Una vez arreglado eso pasamos al problema, el cual se soluciona fácilmente con expresiones regulares y la función `replace()`

```py
import re

txt = ["Incluye toda la informacion", "quien necesitaría", "hola, como estas", "me alegra saberlo"]

txt_1 = ['<code id="2">oracion1</code>', "<code id="7">oracion2</code>', '<code id="221">oracion3</code>', '<code id="216">oracion4</code>']

txt_result = [] # aqui se almacenara la nueva cadena

#creamos una expresion regular
#indica que la palabra oracion debe estar seguida de un numero
regex = re.compile(r'oracion([0-9])')

#recorremos la lista
#ojo, aqui se supone que ambas listas tienen el mismo tamaño
for i in range(len(txt_1)):
  c = re.findall(regex ,txt_1[i]) #buscamos en el texto de cada lista
  #c retorna una lista con las coincidencias
  if c:
    #si la condicion se cumple reemplazamos la cadena "oracion[0-9] por la frase de la otra lista
    txt_result.append(txt_1[i].replace(f"oracion{c[0]}",txt[i]))

#imprimimos el resultado
print(txt_result)
```

**Salida**

```
[
"<code id='2'>Incluye toda la informacion</code>", 
"<code id='7'>quien necesitaría</code>", 
"<code id='221'>hola, como estas</code>", 
"<code id='216'>me alegra saberlo</code>"
]
```

Comment: Pero entonces el XML dentro de las listas no sería válido, porque los atributos XML han de ir entre comillas dobles y no simples. Puedes arreglarlo "dando la vuelta" a las comillas, es decir, usar simples para delimitar cada elemento y dobles dentro de ellos.

Comment: Gracias, ya edite la respuesta :)

Answer (score 1):

Pareces que quieres crear una nueva lista de frases pero que los elementos de la nueva lista tengan concatenado la etiqueta de inicio `<code id="ID">` y filiación `</code>`. Por suerte, puedes hacerlo fácilmente usando el bucle for.

Solo tienes que recorrer tu lista de frases usando el bucle 'for' y en cada iteración concatenarle las etiquetas. Por ejemplo, podrías hacer algo asi:

```py
txt = ["Incluye toda la informacion", "quien necesitaría","quien necesitaría", "hola, como estas", "me alegra saberlo"]
nueva_lista_de_frases = []
index=0
for frase in txt:
    nueva_frase = f'<code id="{index}">' + frase + '</code>'
    nueva_lista_de_frases.append(nueva_frase)
    index+=1
print(nueva_lista_de_frases)
```